# Use FusionCharts in sandbox solution

Tags: highcharts, sandbox, fusioncharts

Has anyone been successfully rendering charts using fusion charts in a sandboxed solution?

How would you get the SWF file onto SharePoint? I included it and deployed it via feature and the Elements.xml looks like the following:

<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Module Name="FusionCharts">
      <File Path="FusionCharts\FCF_Column2D.swf" Url="FusionCharts/FCF_Column2D.swf" />
      <File Path="FusionCharts\FCF_Gantt.swf" Url="FusionCharts/FCF_Gantt.swf" />
   </Module>
</Elements>

When the sandbox solution is deployed, you can access the SWF file from http://sharepointsite/FusionCharts/FCF_Gantt.swf, the browser will attempt to open/save the file. If this file is deployed via farm solution, and be deployed to _layouts folder, which I can access via http://sharepointsite/_layouts/FusionCharts/FCF_Gantt.swf, it renders with error message "invalid xml data". The farm solution deployment is correct because MIME type is properly set to "application/x-shockwave-flash" and thus my custom web part which renders chart using this SWF file works. But if my sandboxed web part is to use the SWF file deployed as site pages, it does not work. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.
Sean

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved with help from DevExpress team. Though SWF can be deployed to SharePoint site document library, you would need Farm Administrator to go into Central Admin pages and set the property in Application Management for the Web application to allow "Permissive". Go to Central Admin -> Application Management -> Select Web Application -> General Settings (Ribbon button), change "Browser File Handling" from "Restrict" to "Permissive".